# PDO и создание нескольких запросов

Tags: php, pdo

Через PDO получаю данные из одной таблицы:

```
$STM = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM zip WHERE zipcode={$address[0]} LIMIT 1", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $STM->fetchAll();
```

Далее делаю вставку в другую таблицу:

```
$STM2 = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO address (zipid, street, build, housing) VALUES (:zipid, :street, :build, :housing)");
echo var_dump($STM2);
$STM2->execute(array('zipid'=>$row[0], 'street'=>$address[1], 'build'=>$address[2], 'housing'=>$address[3]));
```

Уже перепробовал разные варианты, вставку не делает. Если после первого запроса сделать `unset` - второй запрос отработает нормально, но тогда теряется значение  в `$row[0]`.
Помогите разобраться, где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Ключи массива, переданного в `$STM2->execute` должны начинаться с `:`

Comment: fetchAll возвращает двойной массив, нет?
Тоесть $row[0] - это не значение, а массив, поэтому execute и не проходит.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev ключи массива не должны начинаться с :. В этом я уверен.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, когда отправил сюда, голова начала думать по-другому )) Вот этот код заработал: 
`$STM = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM zip WHERE zipcode={$address[0]} LIMIT 1", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$row = $STM->fetch(); 
$zipQ = (int)$row['zipid'];`

```
   $STM2 = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO address (zipid, street, build, housing) VALUES (:zipid, :street, :build, :housing)"); 
    $STM2->execute(array('zipid'=>$zipQ, 'street'=>$address[1], 'build'=>$address[2], 'housing'=>$address[3]));
```

Comment: `(int)` даже не нужен.
Если никаких манипуляций с данными не происходит, советую рассмотреть вариант: `INSTERT INTO address (zipid, street, build, housing) SELECT zip.zipid, zip.street, zip.build, zip.housing FROM zip`